# Spring boot native image can not serialize protobuf object

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, native

I have a method

```
  @Cacheable(value = USER_IDENTITIES_PROTO_CACHE)
    public UserIdentitiesResponseOuterClass.UserIdentitiesResponse findUserIdentitiesProto(UUID userId) {
```

where `UserIdentitiesResponseOuterClass.UserIdentitiesResponse` is a class generated by protobuff.

When using JVM everything works well but in the native image I am getting the exception

> "Failure putting into cache: user_identities_proto. Cannot serialize"

I have tried to add

```
 hints.serialization()
                .registerType(TypeReference.of(UserIdentitiesResponseOuterClass.class))
                .registerType(UserIdentitiesResponseOuterClass.UserIdentity.class)
                .registerType(UserIdentitiesResponseOuterClass.UserIdentitiesResponse.class);
```

but it did not help.

I am using Redis as a cache and using `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` to serialize.

Content of proto file below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package identity;

message UserIdentity {
  string provider = 1;
  string sub = 2;
}

message UserIdentitiesResponse {
  UserIdentity primary = 1;
  repeated UserIdentity identities = 2;
}
```

if an application is run in JVM mode (not native) protobuff object is successfully serialized/deserialized. But in native image the mentioned problem happens.

I am assuming the solution would be to add the   runtime hints.serialization(), but as I mentioned I did it and it did not help, so something is still missing, but it's not clear what exactly

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

"Failure putting into cache: user_identities_proto. Cannot serialize" indicates that GraalVM cannot serialize the `UserIdentitiesResponse` object when you're trying to cache it using Redis.
The `@Cacheable` annotation in Spring uses Java's default serialization mechanism, but protobuf classes do not support Java serialization out of the box. They need to be serialized using protobuf's own serialization mechanisms.
`JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` relies on Java's built-in serialization, which is incompatible with protobuf objects.
You should use a different Redis serializer compatible with protobuf. Spring Data Redis provides a few options, but you might need to implement your own or find a third-party library that supports protobuf.

Comment: which are a few options that Spring Data Redis you are referring to?

Comment: Would be fair to say that your answer is not accurate, if not so say wrong, as if an application is run in JVM mode (not native) protobuff object is successfully serialized/deserialized. But in native image the mentioned problem happens